# Existence of solution to heat equation on a compact manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold (without boundary), I would like to know under which regularity conditions can we solve the heat equation
$$\begin{align}
\partial_tu-\Delta u &= f \\
u(\cdot,0) &= u_0(\cdot)
\end{align}$$
in $M\times[0,T]$?

I have just read [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224662/schauder-estimate-for-the-heat-equation-on-compact-manifolds) which seems to imply that we can solve the equation when $f\in C^{0,0,\alpha}((0,T)\times M,\mathbb{R})$ and $u_0\in C^{2,\alpha}(M,\mathbb{R})$. I would like to know what is the general method of solving when we have this kind of regularity.

The way I learned about solving heat equation in Euclidean domain was by using heat kernel for unbounded domain, and Galerkin approximation on a bounded domain $\Omega$ with boundary. For the Galerkin method, we use the fact that the eigenvectors of the isomorphism
$$
-\Delta:H^2(\Omega)\cap H^1_0(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)
$$
form an orthogonal basis in $L^2(\Omega)$. This seems to rely on the fact that $u\equiv 0$ on $\partial\Omega\times[0,T]$, I don't know if similar result holds on compact manifold without boundary.

Comment: I think you can solve the heat equation in $L^2$ by taking the eigenfunctions and evolving only the eigenvalues.

Comment: @BenMcKay Does the set of eigenvectors of $-\Delta$ also forms an orthogonal basis when our domain is a compact manifold without boundary? I am sorry if this is a silly question but I have very little experience in geometric analysis.

Answer (score 3):

For a brief overview, See Gallot, Hulin, Lafontaine, **Riemannian Geometry**, Springer, 1st edition, p. 198, theorem 4.43, for the spectral theorem for compact Riemannian manifolds: the eigenfunctions are smooth and dense in $L^2$, and the eigenspaces are finite dimenional, so we can pick an orthonormal basis of smooth eigenfunctions. Unfortunately, they give no proof, but they have some references, and I think the proofs are in Colin de Verdiere, *Quasi-modes sur les varietes Riemanniennes*, **Inv.Math.**, 43 (1977), 15-52.

Edit: complete proofs are given in Olivier Lablée, **Spectral Theory in
Riemannian Geometry**, European Mathematical Society, 2010, ; see Theorem 4.3.1. p. 77.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot read French, but thank you very much for the reference.

Comment: You find this also in Shubins book, Theorem 8.3, and I would assume it is in every book containing the phrases pseudodifferential operators or spectral theory.